# listFolder SwiftyDropbox v2

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I´m currently trying to integrate DropBox into my application. I could sign in and make a file request.

Now i want to save the whole current directory in a class called directory. this class gets instantiated by the DirectoryViewModel. You can see the numbered prints in the code snippet and the output shows:

**1
2
3
END --- folders: 0  files: 0
COUNT ITEMS: 0
4
folders count: 4 : files: 1**

so the sequence is wrong ... it should be 3 - 4 - END
I don´t know how to fix that issue ... would be awesome if someone could help me figure it out

```
class Directory{    
var files  = [file]()
var folders  = [folder]()

init()
{
    print("2")
    if let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient {
        print("3")
        // List folder
        client.files.listFolder(path: "").response { response, error in
            print("4")
            if let result = response {
                print("Folder contents:")
                for entry in result.entries {
                    if (self.isFile(testStr: entry.pathLower!)){
                        print("File detected")
                        self.files.append(file(pathDisplay: entry.pathDisplay!, pathLower: entry.pathLower!, name: entry.name))
                    } else {
                        print("Folder detected")
                        self.folders.append(folder(pathDisplay: entry.pathDisplay!, pathLower: entry.pathLower!, name: entry.name))
                    }
                }
                print("folders count: \(self.folders.count) : files: \(self.files.count)")
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class file{

var pathDisplay: String
var pathLower: String
var name: String

init(pathDisplay: String, pathLower: String, name: String) {
    self.pathDisplay = pathDisplay
    self.pathLower = pathLower
    self.name = name
}
```

}

class folder{
    var pathDisplay: String
    var pathLower: String
    var name: String

```
init(pathDisplay: String, pathLower: String, name: String) {
    self.pathDisplay = pathDisplay
    self.pathLower = pathLower
    self.name = name
}
```

}

```
class DirectoryViewModel: NSObject {

var items = [FileFolderItem]()

override init() {
super.init()
    print("1")
     let directory = Directory()
    print("END --- folders: \(directory.folders.count)  files: \(directory.files.count)")
        for folder in directory.folders{
            print("fo")
            self.items.append(FolderItem(pathDisplay: folder.pathDisplay, pathLower: folder.pathLower, name: folder.name))
        }

        for file in directory.files{
            print("fi")

            self.items.append(FolderItem(pathDisplay: file.pathDisplay, pathLower: file.pathLower, name: file.name))
        }
        print("COUNT ITEMS: \(items.count)")
}
```

}

DirectoryViewModel acts as data source in a table view conform to the protocol UITableViewDataSource

```
extension DirectoryViewModel: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].rowCount
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = items[indexPath.section]

    switch item.type{

    case .file:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FileCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? FileCell {
            cell.item = item

            return cell
        }
    case .folder:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FolderCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? FolderCell {
            print("folder added name: ")

            cell.item = item
            return cell
        }

    }
    return UITableViewCell()

}
```

Comment: Your `Directory` initializer returns before the asynchronous callback runs. This is a feature.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Gereon said, the `response` callback for the `listFolder` method (and any other of these Dropbox API call methods in [the Dropbox SwiftyDropbox SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox)), runs asynchronously.

That does mean that your `Directory` initializer may complete before the `response` callback fires. So, you should only run any code that depends on the result from the `response` block once that `response` block does fire (e.g., put it inside the `response` block).